# try {.... } catch(..) only if a certain compile time expression is true

Tags: c++, optimization, try-catch

Here is what we are trying to do

```
try {
    std::uninitialized_copy(...);
} catch(...) {
    if(!boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value) {
       // some cleanup to do here...
    }
    throw;
}
```

We wonder whether the try/catch has a cost if the compile time constant in the `if` is false.

Can the compiler within its "as-if" rights remove the try catch and behave as-if the `std::uninitialized_copy` call appeared without `try` around it?

Or is there something hidden in the C++ specs that requires the compiler to leave it here? As an example, imagine a hypothetical `surrounding_try_blocks()` function that returns the dynamic surrounding try blocks count currently around a frame.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question.Like when you say "does try/catch has a cost..." .What cost did you mean. Merely putting try/catch blocks has some performance cost

Comment: If I understand the question, it's: if `boost::...` is true then the code could be optimised down to just the call to `unitialized_copy` as all it does it catch an exception and then throw it again. But is a compiler permitted to make that optimisation?

Comment: if the compiler optimizes out the if statement your program functions exactly as it would without the try/catch blocks, no? So, I don't see what overhead there would be left for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: @Tommy right. For example, this code always catches any exception (at least as an intermediary step). While if removing the `try`, it could happen that some exceptions are never catched. I'm not quite sure whether I'm understanding all of the consequences. If the call wouldn't merely be to `uninitialized_copy`, but would raise life to more complex object, for example, I'm pretty sure we could have distinct observable behavior, because the Standard allows the compiler to omit unwinding the stack if an exception ends up not being caught anywhere.

Comment: @RedAlert: If it merely optimised out the `if`, you'd be left with `try/catch`, which typically has some overhead. Hence the question: can it eliminate the `try` altogether?

Comment: @ravi with cost, i mean what I asked in the follow-up question. I.e whether it differs in any way from the version without try/catch. I.e performance wise or space-wise.

Comment: I don't see why the "if" part is relevant. My experience is that compilers don't bother optimizing the exceptional path at all (not even `try{throw 42;}catch(...){}` to a nop). But as long as no exception is thrown you shouldn't notice any cost on implementations with so-called zero-cost exception handling. For your specific question, assuming this block is at the end of a function, my main concern would be the copy/move of the exception, but I think elision is allowed in that case.

Comment: @MarcGlisse i certainly will notice some cost. even if only space-wise

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the compiler will do but I know that you can enforce the optimization by yourself:

```
template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if_t<boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value, void>
wrap_uninitialized_copy (...) {
    std::uninitialized_copy(...);
}

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if_t<!boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value, void>
wrap_uninitialized_copy (...) {
    try {
        std::uninitialized_copy(...);
    } catch(...) {
        // some cleanup to do here...
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have summarized the cost of using exception which I have collated from various sources. As what you are asking in your second point is not much clear to me. So I thought it be better to through everything at you. Hope you would pick something of your importance.

To handle exceptions at runtime, programs must do a fair amount of bookkeeping. At each point during
execution, they must be able to identify the objects that require destruction if an exception is thrown; they must make note of each entry to and exit from a try block; and for each try block, they must keep track of the associated catch clauses and the types of exceptions those clauses can handle.

There are things you pay for even if you never use any exception-handling features. You pay for the
space used by the data structures needed to keep track of which objects are fully constructed , and
you pay for the time needed to keep these data structures up to date. These costs are typically quite modest.

Nevertheless, programs compiled without support for exceptions are typically both faster and smaller than their counterparts compiled with support for exceptions

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. "Can the compiler within its "as-if" rights remove the try catch and behave as-if the `std::uninitialized_copy` call appeared without `try` around it?". In other words, can all the work you describe be eliminated, since the compiler can (in principle) see that it's not needed?

Answer (score 0):

From 15.1/8 we find

> A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled
>   exception (15.3). The exception is reactivated with the existing
>   temporary; no new temporary exception object is created...

To me this fairly clearly implies that assuming the evaluation of `boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value` trivially can be shown to have no side effects that the compiler should be able to easily determine that the entire bulk of the catch is unon-executable and that the entire construct can be optimized away. I am not specifically aware of any compiler that does/does not do this however.

My only (slight) doubt is whether the language considers the clearing and resetting of `std::uncaught_exception()` to fall within the "as-if" clause.